# Getting a scroll bar after setting mat-dialog-container padding to 0

Tags: css, angular-material

I have a Dialog Box that has a top Bar which is blue and uses the mat-dialog class and gets some styling from the mat-dialog-container. The problem is the default style of

```
mat-dialog-container {
    display: block;
    padding: 24px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: inherit;
    max-height: inherit;
}
```

which creates this
[image]

I can get rid of this by create my own panel class and apply it to the dialog and ng-deep

```
  ::ng-deep .my-custom-dialog-class {
    mat-dialog-container {
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
```

That fixes my padding but creates a new problem which is i get a scroll bar on the buttom of the dialog window. How can I avoid this or is there another way other then to do the ng-deep ? The form has not changed in size only the padding was set to 0 and i get the scroll bar even so there is nothing to scroll ? Below is a screen shot of what it looks with the padding set to 0 for the container.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `overflow-x:hidden` in `mat-dialog-container`.